# Use a bash argument unlimited times?

Tags: bash, arguments, command-line-arguments

I have a Grep function below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo What directory contains the text files with your data?
read mydirectory
cd $mydirectory
echo What should we name your output?
read $myoutput 
for file in *.txt; do
    grep -q $3 "$file" && grep -q foo "$file" && echo ""$file"">>"$myoutput.txt"
done
```

I really would like to be able to use arguments from the command line to run the script more quickly. I want to be able to hit the up arrow and change a few parameters and run the script again.

The $1 variable will always be the directory with the .txt files I am wanting to run the Grep over. The $2 variable will always be what I want to name my output file. Every parameter thereafter needs to be used in the $3 position of the grep function. My problem is I need to be able fulfill "n" sets of conditions depending on what I am looking for in my files.

For example sometimes it might be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo What directory contains the text files with your data?
read mydirectory
cd $mydirectory
echo What should we name your output/
read $myoutput 
for file in *.txt; do
    grep -q 30 "$file" && grep -q 8 "$file" && grep -q 12 "$file" && grep -q B "$file" && echo ""$file"">>"$myoutput.txt"
done
```

Other times it might be:

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo What directory contains the text files with your data?
read mydirectory
cd $mydirectory
echo What should we name your output?
read $myoutput 
for file in *.txt; do
    grep -q 30 "$file" && grep -q 8 "$file" && grep -q 12 "$file" && grep -q 13 "$file" && grep -q 18 "$file" && grep -q B "$file" && echo ""$file"">>"$myoutput.txt"
done
```

Is there a clever work around for this? I searched online, but couldn't find anything. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have a limited number of txt files? You might want to `grep` all txt files and report the findings grouped by directory and search items, so the user only needs to enter the outputfile.

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag to true and loop over all the search terms. If any search fails, clear the flag.

```
for file in *.txt; do
    match=1
    for term in "${@:3}"; do
        grep -q "$term" "$file" || { match=0; break; }
    done
    ((match)) && echo "$file">>"$myoutput.txt"
done
```

This is a good spot for a helper function.

```
all_found() {
    local file=$1
    shift

    local term
    for term in "$@"; do
        grep -q "$term" "$file" || return 1
    done
    return 0
}

for file in *.txt; do
    all_found "$file" "${@:3}" && echo "$file">>"$myoutput.txt"
done
```